# Как решить задачку на c#?

Tags: c#, html, razor

Подскажите как решить задачку:

Есть код на Razor

```
  @if (Model.PictureModels.Count > 1)
{
    <div class="kt-thumbs">
        <div class="owl-carousel" data-items="1" data-nav="true" data-animateout="slideInUp" data-animatein="slideInUp">
            <div class="page-thumb">
                @foreach (var picture in Model.PictureModels)
                {
                    <a class="item-thumb zoom" href="@picture.ImageUrl">
                        <img src="@picture.ThumbImageUrl" alt="">
                    </a>
                }
            </div>

            <div class="page-thumb">
                @foreach (var picture in Model.PictureModels)
                {
                    <a class="item-thumb zoom" href="@picture.ImageUrl">
                        <img src="@picture.ThumbImageUrl" alt="">
                    </a>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Как сделать так что бы если в первом цикле фотографий > 3 сделать перенос этих фоток во второй page-thumb ?

Comment: В первом цикле `.PictureModels.Take(3)`, во втором - `.PictureModels.Skip(3)`.

Comment: Спасибо. Лаконично, по делу и работает!

Answer (score 0):

Проверить не могу, так что не уверен что написал без ошибок, но что-то типа:

```
 @if (Model.PictureModels.Count > 1)
{
    <div class="kt-thumbs">
        <div class="owl-carousel" data-items="1" data-nav="true" data-animateout="slideInUp" data-animatein="slideInUp">
        @for(var i = 0; i < Model.PictureModels.Count; i++)
        {
            @if (i % 3) {<div class="page-thumb">}

            <a class="item-thumb zoom" href="@picture.ImageUrl">
                        <img src="@picture.ThumbImageUrl" alt="">
            </a>

            @if (i % 3) {</div>}
        }          
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Этим оно сделает многое page-thumb по три фотки в каждом.

Comment: Так много page-thumb быть не должно, только два, а в первом только 3 фотки, все остальные во второй page-thumb.

Comment: Ну так соображайте - куда копать я указал, доделать надо чуть. Никто за вас задачу решать не будет